# Magento tables price list export table structure

Tags: magento-1.7

Hi just thought I'd ask in case someone has already went through the big Magento database.

I'm trying to export a list of all products in the database.

Name
Price
SKU
URL
Stock level

the usual.

I could go through the tables manually but just seeing if anyone already has the list of essential tables sitting around.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
select name, sku, url_path, qty as stock_level
from catalog_product_flat_1 c1
inner join cataloginventory_stock_status c2 on c1.entity_id = c2.product_id
;
```

**Do not forget to adjust the store_id in 'catalog_product_flat_1' to make it match the store you want...**

**EDIT:** The image path of the base image should be added in the last column:

```
select name, sku, url_path, qty as stock_level ,c3.value as base_image
from catalog_product_flat_1 c1
inner join cataloginventory_stock_status c2 on c1.entity_id = c2.product_id
left outer join catalog_product_entity_varchar c3 ON c3.entity_id = c1.entity_id AND c3.attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'image' and entity_type_id = 4 and store_id IN (0,1))
;
```

**Do not forget to adjust the store_id in 'catalog_product_flat_1' and in the IN() condition  (but leave the 0) to make it match the store you want...**

Comment: Thank you very much, that saved me a lot time.  One more annoying question, the image path i noticed is stored in the thumbnail column.  On the live site there is a long unique string path.  Do you know where this is stored, I would like to export the absolute imagepath for the product too.  Thanks

Comment: I have added a second query that will include the base image ;)

Comment: awesome, do you know how catalog_product_flat_1 links to catalog_category_flat_store_1.  I just need to get the name of the category based on specific product

Comment: Please try for yourself, table is catalog_category_product that links product and category... Not doing your homework anymore ;)

Comment: haha yeah I got it after posting. In case anyone else needs it select c1.entity_id, c1.name as product_name, c3.name as category_name, c1.brand_value, c1.sku, c1.price, c1.url_path, c4.qty as stock_level 
FROM catalog_product_flat_1 c1
INNER JOIN catalog_category_product c2
ON c1.entity_id = c2.product_id
INNER JOIN catalog_category_flat_store_1 c3
ON c2.category_id = c3.entity_id
INNER JOIN cataloginventory_stock_status c4
on c1.entity_id = c4.product_id
group by c1.entity_id'